# CRC Mismatch - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle, addressables

I have more than 100 addressable bundles in my application, Some bundles are getting downloaded properly when I open application, but in the same session if I try to download any other bundle then I get CRC mismatch error while downloading addressable, Here is the following error:

> Error while downloading Asset Bundle: CRC Mismatch. Provided 7a52e971, calculated efd3a011 from data. Will not load AssetBundle

- Unity version : 2020.2.1f1
- Addressables version : 1.16.19

Is there any way around to bypass CRC integrity check? Or any possible solution to fix this?

I have disabled checkbox "Use Asset Bundle Crc" and "Use Asset Bundle Crc For Cached Bundles"